# Are 10.10.0.3 and 10.10.0.4 IP's for spammers

Tags: ip-address, spam

I have a site that is getting bombarded by requests from `10.10.0.3` and `10.10.0.4`. I couldn't find where these servers are. What is the best way to regulate this? I could just deny those IP's but I have a feeling it would just start using other IP's.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe some of your local machines got a trojan?

Comment: Where are you seeing these addresses? TCP connections to your server (if so, what port or service)? "Received:" headers in messages? Somewhere else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IP addresses 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255 are [reserved](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) for private networks, i.e.
the traffic you see is coming somewhere from your internal network, so try to figure out which machines those are, or contact your hosting provider and have them poke around what their 10.10.0.3 machine is doing.

Comment: If Jason is behind a NAT'ing firewall, it could be NAT'ing an external address that's sending spam.  Alternatively, it could also just be something else that's hosted by the same provider.

Comment: While it's most likely true that those IPs he is seeing are on his LAN, my company is currently about to cut loose an ISP that is exposing THEIR 10.0.0.0/8 IPs to -our- LAN which is also on 10.0.0.0/8.  Highly annoying.

Answer (score 3):

You can't figure out where those servers are on the Internet because that's an internal Intranet IP address. Whoever is spamming you is apparently on the same network as you. You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 3):

In response to the other answers here:
It could also be forged IP headers. Ask your ISP to do a proper job (ie, block spoofed IP's).

Answer (score 2):

Those are rfc1918 private address blocks, and cannot be used on the internet, and generally are not routable, though I suppose that it may well be that you can forge them as a from  address and not have them dropped.

These are either from your local network (if it is using a private adress space because internet access is NATed), or you can just drop them (include all the rfc1918 address spaces).

Comment: +1 for RFC citation.  Give a man a fish...

Comment: "We've traced the call. It's coming from inside the house."